# Link's href value gets lost

Tags: nodes, theming, 8, navigation

I am trying to make a link on node by returning this array(The array is being formed in the function by the name buildLinks() ):

```
     $links[$key] = array(

    'title' => $definition['title'],

    'href' => $this->urlGenerator->generateFromRoute('module.show_format.' . $entity->getEntityTypeId(), array('module_format' => $key, 'entity' => $entity->id())),
  );
```

but on the page the link title is appearing but the link's href value gets lost(I mean title is appearing but it is not appearing as link).What am I doing wrong?

Update: The above array is being returned over here:

```
    return array(
    '#theme' => 'links__entity__module',
    '#links' => $this->linkBuilder->buildLinks($this->request->attributes->get($entity_type)),
  );
```

So is there is a possiblity that I am doing something wrong over here?

Comment: are you sure the $this-> is actually returning a correct value?

Comment: @Geoff yes $this-> is working correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the documentation around that theme function is out of date. Please open a bug report for that.

Have a look at [template_preprocess_links](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_links/8), it is using `url`, not `href`. Also not that `url` is a `Drupal\Core\Url` object, not a path, so your code should look like this:

```
$links[$key] = array(
  'title' => $definition['title'],
  'url' => Url::fromRoute('module.show_format.' . $entity->getEntityTypeId(), array('module_format' => $key, 'entity' => $entity->id())),
);
```